# Complexity of counting all connected subgraphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, counting-complexity

Let G be a connected graph.

> What is the complexity of counting all *connected subgraphs* if G is of the following types?
>
> - G is general.
> - G is planar.
> - G is bipartite.

I don't care about any structures or ..., just need to count all the connected subgraphs!
I'm also interested in the complexity of counting all connected subgraphs *with exactly k nodes* in G.

Pointers to papers and books are also welcomed!

Comment: Are you aware that the list in the question is not formatted correctly?  http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-to-ask-a-good-question/328#328  If you do not care about formatting, that is fine.  But I am not sure if anyone wants to spend time to answer your question when you do not want to spend time to format your question properly.  (I am not saying that I know the answer.)

Comment: Also, do you care about enumerating connected subgraphs of arbitrary size/order/structure/..., or do you wish them to be spanning, or anything else?

Comment: There seems to work on counting connected *spanning* subgraphs. Page 32 of Sokal's "multivariate Tutte Polynomial" connects spanning subgraph polynomial to reliability polynomial which has a huge literature

Comment: I'm sorry, my previous answer on using Kirchhoff's theorem was wrong. I thought about an inclusion-exclusion argument but this might be infeasible.

Comment: [This paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/ietfec/e91-a.9.2314) isn't exactly what you asked for, but the paper and [its references](http://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/transfun/E91.A/9/E91.A_2314/_cit) may help in developing some ideas.

Answer (score 14):

Welsh states that the problem #P-complete even in the most restricted case (counting the number of connected subgraphs of a planar bipartite graph). See the bottom of [page 305](http://books.google.com/books?id=pe3CJmT_EOYC&pg=PA305&dq=%22number+of+connected+subgraphs%22+%22%23p-complete%22&hl=en&ei=tG9hTdzWHInYgQeTnJSpAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22number%20of%20connected%20subgraphs%22%20%22%23p-complete%22&f=false) in Welsh, Dominic (1997), "Approximate Counting", *Surveys in Combinatorics*, Bailey, R. A., ed., Cambridge University Press, pp. 287–324.

In context, though, I wonder whether he really means connected spanning subgraphs. And that leads me to wonder which version of the problem you want: connected spanning subgraphs, connected subgraphs that need not be spanning, or connected induced subgraphs?

Answer (score 6):

This is a response to David's answer. Without having looked at that book yet I'd guess the problem is counting connected spanning subgraphs, because this is the point x=1 y=2 of the Tutte polynomial, and the author was interested in that. But in fact I think those three problems reduce quite easily from counting connected spanning subgraph problem. The following reductions should work for either exact counting or approximation, though I think the problem for approximation is still open.

Counting connected spanning subgraphs reduces to counting connected subgraphs (sketch): 
Take a graph G in which we wish to count spanning subgraphs. Attach a $K_A$ to each vertex. If $A$ is chosen large enough, typical connected subgraphs of the resulting graph correspond N-to-1 to connected spanning subgraphs in G, where N is easy to compute.

Counting connected spanning subgraphs reduces to counting connected induced subgraphs (sketch):
Let G be a graph in which we wish to count spanning subgraphs. Divide each edge in two, so there are now |V|+|E| vertices. Attach a $K_A$ to each of the original vertices that were in G. If $A$ is chosen large enough, typical connected induced subgraphs of the resulting graph correspond N-to-1 to connected spanning subgraphs in G, where N is easy to compute.

Here's another interpretation of the question: what about counting unlabelled connected subgraphs? This is $\#P$ hard even for trees: L.A. Goldberg and M. Jerrum, Counting unlabelled subtrees of a tree is #P-Complete, LMS Journal of Computation and Mathematics, 3 (2000) 117-124.

Comment: You don't need to attach a clique, right? You could attach anything that has a lot of connected subgraphs, as long as you attach the same thing to each vertex. So you could do these reductions while preserving both planarity and bipartiteness.